# What is a mathematical (described with a function) equivalent of mirroring bits?

Tags: function, math, assembly, representation, data-representation

So imagine we have a function F(x), where x can be any 8bit number, and our functions returns mirrored number. How could this function look in decimal format or maybe do you even would think of binary representation?

Examples:

- F(0b1110.0000) = 0b0000.0111
- F(0b1001.0000) = 0b0000.1001

Comment: If you consider your word to be a polynomial and its bits to be coefficients of the polynomial, then reversing the bits is substituting *x* for x⁻¹ modulo 2^(n-1) where *n* is the number of bits in the word.